# Kill command does the job but gives error

Tags: linux, shell, kill, kill-process

I'm using shell script to stop a python service and to do that I'm executing the below command.

`ps -ef | grep service.py | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`

After executing I'm getting below error:

**kill: sending signal to 487225 failed: Operation not permitted**

But, when I check the terminal where the process is running, it terminates.

`/home/saakhan/Documents/scripts/cluster-helpers.sh: line 75: 526839 Killed                  python3 src/service.py`

Now, in my shell script I'm checking for the error if any, while stopping the service. So, it calls that error function which displays "Failed to stop the Service" even though the service is stopped successfully.

Do I need to change the command for this ?

**Note: I have to use 'kill' only and not 'pkill**

Comment: Parsing the output of `ps` is error-prone. Compare the PID numbers in `kill: sending signal to 487225 failed: Operation not permitted` and `526839 Killed`. There seems to be a matching process which is owned by a different user. Your command will try to kill *every* process that contains a substring which matches the *regular expression* `service.py`, where `.` means *any character*. Inserting `tee /tmp/processes.log` into the pipe before `awk` might show more processes than you expect. BTW: You should use `kill -9` as a last resort only if a process cannot be terminated using other signals.

Comment: @Bodo Sorry, my bad. I didn't notice the PIDs. Thanks for pointing it out. I filtered the results based on user process and then killed it so it worked.
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bodo pointed out, there was more than one PIDs and only one of them got killed while the other showed error as it wasn't started by the same user.

I changed the grep command to filter the process started by the same user and then killed it, so it worked.

Update:

I used this command to successfully run my code and terminate the app as needed.

```
ps -u | grep service.py | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: Sorry for not doing it early as I'm new to adding questions and answers here.

Comment: The command `grep service.py` will find any line of `ps` output that contains `service` followed by any single character, followed by `py` anywhere in the line, e.g. also in the username or arguments. In a regular expression, `.` means "any character". I suggest to replace it with `grep -Fw service.py` because this will search for the fixed string `service.py` as a single word. It does not fix all problems, though.